# Remove files created on Weekend

Tags: delete

I am using Debian 10 Buster and I am a Linux newby. It´s never too late..

I am collecting pictures in order to create a long-term time lapse video of a construction site across the street.

All of the pictures are in a directory inluding pictures taken Saturday and Sunday.

The filenames are formated like this:

```
YYYY-MM-DD_HHMM.jpg
```

example

```
2021-05-07_1012.jpg
```

Now i am trying to remove pictures that were created Saturdays and Sundays.

When executing below (from another thread here) I am able to list all files created Saturdays and Sundays:

```
find -type f -printf '%Ta\t%p\n' | egrep "^(Sat|Sun)" | cut -f 2-
```

The question is:
How do I modify this line into a delete statement to remove the files?

Another option could be (i store the files on a nas) the exclude the files when copying them into my working directory.

I use rsync to copy the files over.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately i do not think this answers my question or you need to help me understand it.

As far as i can see, this generically removes files based on patterns. 
Here there is no pattern as such, I would need to extact the weekdays from the file properties and then delete Sat and Sun only.

Comment: The relevant part for you is piping to `xargs`, the `find` command in that question does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Appending `xargs rm` to the command, so that we have:

`find -type f -printf '%Ta\t%p\n' | egrep "^(Sat|Sun)" | cut -f 2- | xargs rm`

Will delete any of the files that match your search results. You can also use `rm -v` to view which files were deleted.

`xargs` reads items from the standard input, and as you said in a comment, it can be used with patterns. Our pattern here however is defined with `find`, `printf`, `egrep` and `cut`.

After running your command to locate the files, the relative paths are printed, but when we use `xargs rm` those paths are given to `rm` via `xargs`, and subsequently deleted.

Comment: Thank you!

that works! so the first hint already had the answer but brxken pointed me to the solution.